# How to elevate privileges in sbt-built docker image

Tags: scala, docker, kubernetes, sbt

I'm trying to debug my application, which is running in kubernetes in a docker container. The image is built using sbt native-packager docker plugin. I would like to login to the pod and investigate there, but the default user account (`demiourgos728`) has no privileges and I don't know how to switch to a root account.

I've tried running `kubectl exec --user=root image -- bash` (user not found), also tried to run `su -` in the image (authentication failure), with no success. The base image used for building the app is java:8.

These are my docker settings in build.sbt:

```
.settings(
    Seq(
      dockerBaseImage := "java:8",
      publishArtifact := false,
      dockerExposedPorts ++= Seq(8088), 
      packageName in Docker := "api-endpoint"
    ))
```

Answer (score 2):

`--user=root` in `kubectl` is for authenticating on your kube-apiserver and not forcing the container to execute a command as a user in the container.

If you are running docker on your nodes and want to force escalate to `root` you can ssh to the node where your container is running and then run:

```
$ docker exec -it --user=root <container-id> bash
# or
$ docker exec -it -u root <container-id> bash
```

You can find out the node where your pod/container is running by using:

```
$ kubectl describe pod <pod-id>
```